# How to count elements with condition in a table in Big Query

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this in Big Query:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| IDm |  A  |  B  |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 102 | 0.9 | 0.3 |
| 100 | 0.3 | 0.1 |
| 199 | 0.1 | 0.6 |
| 102 | 0.2 | 0.9 |
| 102 | 0.4 | 0.3 |
```

The "IDm" items are not unique, there are multiple "IDm" with the same value with different "A" and "B" values. I want to know how many times every single "IDm" satisfies the condition "A+B > 1".
How can i do this? I usualy use Python and Pandas to do this, but is there an SQL way to do it? I'd like to run the query on the Big Query web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT IDm, COUNTIF(A + B > 1 ) qualified_counts
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY IDm
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row IDm qualified_counts     
1   102 2    
2   100 0    
3   199 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT IDm, COUNT(CASE WHEN A + B > 1 THEN 1 END) AS cond_match_count
FROM tbl
GROUP BY IDm
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use `countif()`:

```
select countif( a + b > 1)
from t;
```

Or:

```
select count(*)
from t
where a + b > 1;
```

If you have duplicate `idm` values and want a unique count:

```
select count(distinct idm)
from t
where a + b > 1;
```